# Gitlab Testhosts for multiple Braches

Tags: linux, gitlab

Does anybody know a way to test webapplications while developing in gitlab?
A solution like: branchname.myserver.com uses a automatic exported branch as document root?

Specific:

Bind it to a Webapplication, so dynamic virual hosts appear if I create a branch and maybe a ci...

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's pretty straightforward: you need to define a set of stages (at least one) and mark each job with

```
- only: branchname
```

and then define a CI routine to deploy it into this specific server/docroot.